# Lwuit virtual keyboard error

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

When I click something in the keyboard this error is coming up

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.lwuit.VirtualKeyboard.actionCommand(+81)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Form.actionCommandImpl(+81)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Button.fireActionEvent(+47)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Button.released(+11)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Button.pointerReleased(+14)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Form.pointerReleased(+186)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Dialog.pointerReleased(+6)
    at com.sun.lwuit.VirtualKeyboard.pointerReleased(+19)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Component.pointerReleased(+10)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.handleEvent(+151)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.edtLoopImpl(+118)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.invokeAndBlock(+84)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.invokeAndBlock(+6)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Form.showModal(+416)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Dialog.showModal(+86)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Dialog.show(+89)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Dialog.showPacked(+411)
    at com.sun.lwuit.VirtualKeyboard.show(+7)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Dialog.showDialog(+9)
    at com.sun.lwuit.VirtualKeyboard.showKeyboard(+135)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.setShowVirtualKeyboard(+23)
    at com.sun.lwuit.TextArea.pointerReleased(+25)
    at com.sun.lwuit.TextField.pointerReleased(+189)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Form.pointerReleased(+186)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Component.pointerReleased(+10)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.handleEvent(+151)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.edtLoopImpl(+118)
    at com.sun.lwuit.Display.mainEDTLoop(+208)
    at com.sun.lwuit.RunnableWrapper.run(+245)
```

It is not even working in LWUITDemo.jar also....is there any solution for this
or is there anyway to disable virtual keyboard in midlet

Comment: I'm not seeing this in the latest SVN of both the LWUIT demo and LWUIT. You can always disable the LWUIT VKB by setting the default VKB to null but we don't recommend it since it will also disable the native VKB when applicable. If you can reproduce it with the SE port and update the line numbers to actual line numbers in LWUIT code it might provide more information.

Comment: in the svn trunk designer demo itself the kvb is showing error

Comment: i meant resource editor in trunk/www/designer

Comment: i compiled /trunk/UI and used it now i get this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/impl/ImplementationFactory
 at com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(+28)
 at com.lic.mobile.ui.Main.startApp(+4)
 at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletProxy.startApp(+7)
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.Scheduler.schedule(+270)
 at com.sun.midp.main.Main.runLocalClass(+28)
 at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main(+80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is specific to the current version of the LWUIT designer and will be fixed in an upcoming update.

The compilation issue you are experiencing is due to the usage of the UI project rather than using the appropriate port (e.g. the MIDP/UI project).